# NAT Error Message - Usage limit exceeded

Tags: mac, internet, port-forwarding, nat

Trying to configure a port to use for Vuze. Using the NAT/server port test, I was getting a message saying the connection timed out, the port was probably closed. I went back and made sure to open the specific port on my router, firewall, etc, but now I'm getting "NAT Error - Usage limit exceeded (173.32.41.24:0).

I'm on a mac pro running leopard, trial versions of intego netbarrier and virusbarrier. Network utilities and netbarrier both claim the port is open. I've tested a bunch of other ports, but all give the same message.

Comment: It sounds like you are double natting. Are the router and the firewall both set to give out DHCP?

Comment: what's the router make/model(/firmware)?

Comment: @ridogi - didn't even know the firewall could do that..
@quack - cheap Belkin...can look it up later, atm Vuze is working at full health for some reason, though the NAT/firewall test is saying the same thing...will have to look into it later

Comment: I think we need some specifics as to model and local IP address of the router, firewall, and computer to give us a more complete picture of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ISP is NATting you as well.

Comment: encryption turned on after a restart with the normal message about the ISP provider limiting bandwidth...could that be why it's working now?

Comment: @kato: perhaps your ISP is simply filtering out p2p traffic then :)

Comment: Not that you should even download torrents without encryption enabled. Even legal ones.